# Error printing the length of the longest word?

Tags: python

I am writing a function that is supposed to print out the 3 largest words of a text file. Once those 3 words are printed out, I am supposed to create a function that will say how many characters are in those words. The three largest words are 13 characters, but for some reason my program is saying that they are 11 characters.

Here is my program:

```
def main():
    real_longest = ['']
    filename = input("What is the filename?")
    with open(filename) as f:
        linenum = 1
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            longest = ''
            for word in words:
                if len(longest) < len(word):
                    longest = word
            print("Line", linenum, "has", longest, "as the longest word.")
            if len(longest) > len(real_longest[0]):
                real_longest = [longest]
            elif len(longest) == len(real_longest[0]):
                real_longest.append(longest)
            linenum += 1
            print(longest)
    with open(filename) as f:
        for word in real_longest:
            print("This word is one of the largest:", word)
            print(len(longest))

main()
```

Here is what it returns:

```
What is the filename?test.txt
Line 1 has Working as the longest word.
Working
Line 2 has possibilities as the longest word.
possibilities
Line 3 has scrambled as the longest word.
scrambled
Line 4 has letters. as the longest word.
letters.
Line 5 has  as the longest word.

Line 6 has difficulties as the longest word.
difficulties
Line 7 has permutations. as the longest word.
permutations.
Line 8 has signature as the longest word.
signature
Line 9 has permutations. as the longest word.
permutations.
Line 10 has unscrambled as the longest word.
unscrambled
This word is one of the largest: possibilities
11
This word is one of the largest: permutations.
11
This word is one of the largest: permutations.
11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are not printing the length of the `word`, instead you are printing the length of `longest` variable, which points to the longest word in the last line (not the real longest word from the file) , In the particular example - `'unscrambled'` , and hence the 11 length.

You should print the length of the `word`. Example -

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for word in real_longest:
        print("This word is one of the largest:", word)
        print(len(word))       # <---------- changed here from `len(longest)` .
```

Comment: Such a simple mistake! Thank you for clarifying, this works!